# How to using NSAffineTransform

Tags: ios

I want to use `NSAffineTransform` but not get an alert:

> "Unknown type name 'NSAffineTransform' did you mean 'CGAffineTransform'?"

How to use it?

Comment: You are looking for iOS or Mac?

Answer (score 1):

The NSAffineTransform class is not available on iOS. You will have to use the C-based [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) API instead.

Answer (score 1):

NSAffineTransform class is available in `Cocoa` framework for the Mac OS X development. And  CGAffineTransform class is available in the `Cocoa Touch` framework for the iOS application  development. If you implementing application in iOS Use CGAffineTransform.